# Google sheets: App script: Script function openAllLinks() could not be found

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to make this script work so that when you press the button all of the hyperlinks open.
I can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong!
I have very little experience with this and have tried to use AI to help so might not have set it up correctly..??

Any suggestions?

Here is the google sheet I'm using:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FIFywGyt5SPrvl1z-V01JU1fMQRd1E0yIXETs4w7Ufs/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for any ideas - in advance,
Matt

This is the script I've used:

```js
function openAllLinks() {
  // Get the selected range
  const selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();

  // Filter for cells containing hyperlinks
  const withLinks = selection.getRichTextValues()
    .map((row, rowIndex) => row.map((cellRichTextValue, colIndex) => {
      // Check if cell contains hyperlinks
      const links = cellRichTextValue.getRuns().filter(run => run.getLinkUrl());
      return links.length > 0 ? links[0].getLinkUrl() : null; // Get the first link URL
    }))
    .filter(row => row.some(cell => cell !== null));

  // Open each hyperlink in a new browser tab
  withLinks.forEach(row => {
    row.forEach(cell => {
      if (cell) {
        UrlFetchApp.fetch(cell, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
      }
    });
  });

  // Show a confirmation message
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Links opened successfully!');
}
```

I've tried looking on various Google support forums and have posted but not had any luck yet!
I've also tried AI but seem to end up going down a rabbit hole even more!

Comment: Judging by the comments in the code, I assume that you are trying to open these links in your browser tabs. I do not think it is possible with Google Apps Script: it operates server-side and does not have access to your browser.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  The big picture is that I'm trying to open a selected list of url hyperlinks from a google sheet with one click. I've tried using AI - but out of my depth! Could you suggest an easier approach? The only constraint is that pop-ups are not allowed in this scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I do not think it is possible to do it from a spreadsheet at all.  You will need another approach with some custom JS webpage.  Or maybe somebody else will come up with an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You select some cells including the hyperlinks, and you want to retrieve those hyperlinks.
- You want to open the retrieved hyperlinks with your browser.

In the current stage, the hyperlink cannot be directly opened by Google Apps Script. In this case, Javascript is used on a dialog or a sidebar. So, how about the following flow?

1. Select cells including the hyperlinks.
2. Run the script.
3. Retrieve all hyperlinks from the selected cells.
4. Open a dialog. And, the hyperlinks are opened with Javascript on the dialog.

When this flow is reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you run this script, please select cells including the hyperlinks, and run the script. By this, the retrieved hyperlinks are opened with the browser as new tabs.

```js
function openAllLinks() {
  // Get the selected range
  const selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();

  // --- I modified the below script.
  const withLinks = selection.getRichTextValues()
    .flatMap(row => row.flatMap(cellRichTextValue => {
      const links = cellRichTextValue.getRuns().filter(run => run.getLinkUrl());
      return links.length > 0 ? links[0].getLinkUrl() : [];
    }));

  if (withLinks.length == 0) {
    Browser.msgBox("No URLs were found.");
    return;
  }
  const opens = withLinks.map(url => `window.open('${url}', '_blank');`).join("");
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<html><script>${opens};google.script.host.close();</script></html>`);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
  // ---

  // Show a confirmation message
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Links opened successfully!');
}
```

#### References:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)
- [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for looking into this for me - after a bit of fiddling, I managed to make it work through my browser!! Can I just ask, does this script/procedure need popups enabled to run or could it run if pop-ups were disabled. The use scenario for this is withing an online tutoring platform which has a chrome web browser widget with popups blocked - ive tries using the sheet within the browser but pop ups are stopping it from working? p.s can I buy you a coffee?!

Comment: @Matt Bowen Thank you for replying. About `after a bit of fiddling, I managed to make it work through my browser`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Can I just ask, does this script/procedure need popups enabled to run or could it run if pop-ups were disabled. The use scenario for this is withing an online tutoring platform which has a chrome web browser widget with popups blocked`, I think that it's yes. But, I would like to recommend testing it in your situation.

Comment: @Matt Bowen About `ive tries using the sheet within the browser but pop ups are stopping it from working?`, I would like to recommend to confirm about the popup in your browser.

Comment: @Matt Bowen About `p.s can I buy you a coffee?!`, if your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thank you - have found button!  Do you think there is a solution for the popups in this scenario?    https://my.pencilapp.com/spaces/65c4ba4bea8569b2d3d96bbf?utm_source=copy_link&utm_medium=invite

Comment: @Matt Bowen Thank you for your response. About `Do you think there is a solution for the popups in this scenario?`, unfortunately, I cannot test this situation. So, when you want a clear answer to this question. I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help users think of your new question. I believe that you will obtain a clear answer. I deeply apologize that I cannot test the situation of your new question.